# After voting 'off topic' with migration to other site, be able to see the other site

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

When I vote a question as 'off topic', I'm given the option to migrate the question to one of five other sites. After I submit the vote, and then click the 'close' link again, I'm able to see that I voted to close the question as 'off topic', but I'm not able to see the site to which I voted to migrate the question.

Would it be possible to put a little "migrated to foosite.stackexchange.com" blurb in the popup box? Maybe the little header would read something like **off topic - migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com** if I voted to migrate the question to programmers.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: That's the type of edit up with which I will not put!

Comment: I would love to see "programmers" and other sites added! The 5 listed are just not sufficient.